# Estimation of summation

Tags: summation

A question told me to estimate the summation of  $$\sqrt i$$ from 0 to 10000000 using integrals
$$\sum_{i=0}^{10000000}\sqrt{i}=?$$
Is it okay to estimate by integrating it from 1 to 10000000, or am I supposed to use other methods like Riemann's Sum or?

Comment: Do we have $x\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: x = $$i$$ @AndrewChin

Comment: Is it $$\sum_{n=1}^{10000000} \sqrt n$$ that you're looking for?

Comment: Yep, but n = $$i$$

EDIT: It's $$\sum_{i=0}^{10000000}\sqrt{i}=?$$

@AndrewChin

Answer (score 0):

If you let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then you can think of the sum $$ \sum_{x=0}^{10\,000\,000} \sqrt{x}$$ as the area under the curve of the function $f(x)$ as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $10\,000\,000$.

So, we find that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x=0}^{10\,000\,000}\sqrt{x} \approx \int_0^{10\,000\,000} \sqrt{x}\,dx &= \frac23 x^{3/2}\bigg|_0^{10\,000\,000}\\
 &= \frac{20\,000\,000\,000 \sqrt{10}}3\\
 &\approx 2.1082 \times 10^{10}.
\end{align*}
In fact, this approximation is pretty good since $$ \sum_{n=0}^{10\,000\,000} \sqrt{n} = 2.10818 \times 10^{10}.$$

Comment: Will this also apply if x = $$i$$

Comment: Yes! I believe in this case, $x$ and $i$ are just placeholder variables. So it will apply.